# Spring Data JDBC и отношение Многие-ко-многим

Tags: kotlin, spring-data, many-to-many, spring-jdbc

Читаю Spring in Action (6 издание). Код из раздела с Spring Data JDBC упрямо отказывается работать. Ниже я максимально упростил, написанное в книге (3 простейшие таблицы в базе и 2 класса в коде), при этом 1 в 1 воспроизвел ошибку.

База данных H2.

Создал 3 таблицы (код из `schema.sql`): `Test_First` и `Test_Second` связаны между собой таблицей `Refs`. Принцип построения таблиц, как в книге.

```
create table if not exists Test_First (
    id identity,
    name_first varchar(50) not null
);

create table if not exists Test_Second (
    id identity,
    name_second varchar(50) not null
);

create table if not exists Refs (
    test_first bigint not null,
    test_first_key bigint not null,
    test_second bigint not null
);

alter table Refs add foreign key (test_second) references Test_Second(id);
```

Сразу заполнил таблицу `Test_Second` (код из `data.sql`):

```
delete from Test_First;
delete from Test_Second;
delete from Refs;

insert into Test_Second (name_second) values ('1_S_Name');
insert into Test_Second (name_second) values ('2_S_Name');
insert into Test_Second (name_second) values ('3_S_Name');
insert into Test_Second (name_second) values ('4_S_Name');
```

Теперь код программы. Язык - Kotlin.

Таблицы. `TestFirst` кроме прочего содержит массив из `TestSecond`.

```
@Table
class TestFirst(
    @Column("NAME_FIRST") val name: String,
) {
    @Id private var id: Long? = null
    private val seconds: MutableList<TestSecond> = mutableListOf()

    fun addSecond(second: TestSecond) {
        seconds.add(second)
    }
}
```

и

```
@Table
class TestSecond(
    @Column("NAME_SECOND") val name: String,
) {
    @Id private var id: Long? = null
}
```

Репозитории для обеих таблиц наследуются от `CrudRepository` без каких-либо дополнительных изменений.

Собственно вот код, который сначала получает все данные из таблицы `Test_Second`, добавляет некоторые из них в экземпляр класса `TestFirst` и пытается его сохранить.

```
@Autowired
lateinit var firstRepo: TestFirstRepo
@Autowired
lateinit var secondRepo: TestSecondRepo

@Bean
fun command(): CommandLineRunner = CommandLineRunner {
    val secondList: List<TestSecond> = secondRepo.findAll().toList()
    val first1 = TestFirst("1_F_NAME").apply {
        addSecond(secondList[0])
        addSecond(secondList[1])
        addSecond(secondList[2])
    }
    firstRepo.save(first1)
    val first2 = TestFirst("2_F_NAME").apply {
        addSecond(secondList[1])
        addSecond(secondList[2])
        addSecond(secondList[3])
    }
    firstRepo.save(first2)
}
```

В общем, где-то тут и возникает ошибка. Будто JDBC не понимает, что ему нужно создать запись в таблице `Test_First`, а после этого добавить запись в таблицу `Refs`. А я не знаю, как ему это объяснить.

Вот сама ошибка:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Столбец "TEST_FIRST" не найден
Column "TEST_FIRST" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO "TEST_SECOND" ("NAME_SECOND", "ID", "TEST_FIRST", "TEST_FIRST_KEY") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) [42122-214]
```

Книга написана для Java, но не думаю, что в этом большая проблема. И вроде как такой код должен работать, но нет. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Похоже, что в книге ошибка. Для разрешения вопроса нужно следующее.

1. Создать в проекте класс, идентичный таблице `Refs`, а также немного изменить класс `TestSecond`:

```
@Table
class Refs(
    @Column("TEST_SECOND")
    val id: Long?,
)

@Table
class TestSecond(
    @Column("NAME_SECOND") val name: String,
) {
    @Id var id: Long? = null
}
```

2. Внести изменения в класс `TestFirst` - теперь он будет накапливать экземпляры класса `Refs`, а не `TestSecond` (как раз об этом в книге ни слова):

```
@Table
class TestFirst(
    @Column("NAME_FIRST") val name: String,
) {
    @Id
    private var id: Long? = null
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "TEST_FIRST")
    private val seconds: MutableList<Refs> = mutableListOf()

    fun addSecond(second: TestSecond) {
        seconds.add(Refs(second.id))
    }
}
```

Как видно, формально мы вызываем метод, в который передаем экземпляр `TestSecond`, вместо которого в массив добавляется новый экземпляр `Refs`.

В базе данных изменения не нужны.